# Formik FiedlArray - checkbox, label/textfield combo

Tags: formik

I am trying to integrate a formik FieldArray on a website -- where they want to have checkboxes and labels and if its a new entry to have it as a textfield.

https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays

I'm following this example but I am unsure how you detect if its a newly added field - and how to toggle between a textfield or a label near the checkbox for something like this?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bouman-ycesi5

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";

const initialValues = {
  friends: [
    {
      name: "billybob",
      checkbox_name: true
    }
  ]
};

const AddGoals = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Invite friends</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray name="friends">
            {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
              <div>
                {values.friends.length > 0 &&
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}>
                      <div className="col">
                        <label>
                          <Field
                            type="checkbox"
                            name={`friends.${index}.checkbox_name`}
                          />
                          xxxx
                        </label>

                        <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.name`}>Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          placeholder="Jane Doe"
                          type="text"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          component="div"
                          className="field-error"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="secondary"
                          onClick={() => remove(index)}
                        >
                          X
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="secondary"
                  onClick={() => push({ name: "", checkbox_name: false })}
                >
                  Add Goal
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </FieldArray>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<AddGoals />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

so would we make a condition using a flag new

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";

const initialValues = {
  friends: [
    {
      name: "billybob",
      checkbox_name: true,
      new: false
    }
  ]
};

const AddGoals = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Invite friends</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray name="friends">
            {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
              <div>
                {values.friends.length > 0 &&
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}>
                      <div className="col">
                        <label>
                          <Field
                            type="checkbox"
                            name={`friends.${index}.checkbox_name`}
                          />
                          {!friend.new ? (
                            <span>{friend.name}</span>
                          ) : (
                            <Field
                              name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                              placeholder="Jane Doe"
                              type="text"
                            />
                          )}
                        </label>
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          component="div"
                          className="field-error"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="secondary"
                          onClick={() => remove(index)}
                        >
                          X
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="secondary"
                  onClick={() =>
                    push({ name: "", checkbox_name: false, new: true })
                  }
                >
                  Add Goal
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </FieldArray>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<AddGoals />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I have a basic sandbox for this - https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-17egbf?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood you correctly you want to have a to-do list whereby clicking on Add goal button will add an input box so the user can input in it and by clicking on the save button you need to render a list with already saved todo along with checkbox and label only this time.

If that's the case you can do so by following this snippet.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";

const intialFriendVlaues = {
  name: "",
  invited: true,
  isNew: true
};

const initialValues = {
  friends: [intialFriendVlaues]
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Invite friends</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      // onSubmit={async (values) => {
      //   await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
      //   alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      // }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        try {
          actions.resetForm({
            values: {
              friends: values.friends.map((friend) => ({
                ...friend,
                isNew: false
              }))
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray name="friends">
            {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
              <div>
                {values.friends.length > 0 &&
                  values.friends.map((friend, index, self) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                          {friend.isNew ? (
                            <div className="row">
                              <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.name`}>
                                Name
                              </label>
                              <Field
                                name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                                placeholder="Jane Doe"
                                type="text"
                              />
                              <ErrorMessage
                                name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                                component="div"
                                className="field-error"
                              />
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            <label>
                              <Field
                                type="checkbox"
                                name={`friends.${index}.invited`}
                              />
                              {friend.name}
                            </label>
                          )}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="secondary"
                            onClick={() => remove(index)}
                          >
                            X
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      {self.length - 1 === index ? (
                        <div className="row">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="secondary"
                            onClick={() => push(intialFriendVlaues)}
                          >
                            Add Goal
                          </button>
                          <button type="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                      ) : null}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  ))}
              </div>
            )}
          </FieldArray>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: your demo doesn't appear to load?

Comment: It won't run here you will have to copy the code and run it on code sandbox or on your local.

Comment: What about load it into the sandbox

Comment: @TheOldCounty Here is the code-sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-benji-z8ecr1?file=/src/App.js